# How should I name styles and Themes in Android

Tags: android

What is the convention for naming xml styles in Android.

I have seee things like

```
Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem
```

and

```
Theme.Black
```

If I extend these in my own styles how should I name it?

Answer (score 1):

The styles can follow the following convention `X` style parent of `Y` then you should write `Y.X`

see [Android UI best practices I have found out so far](http://www.dev-articles.com/article/Android-ui-best-practices-I-have-found-out-so-far-380001)